# Where to find documentation for QuickBooks database

Tags: crystal-reports, report, quickbooks

I have to write a bunch of reports using data from QuickBooks.  Do you know where I can find documentation from Intuit for the structure of the database used by QuickBooks Enterprise ?

I tried to find some kind of support from Intuit but they are not providing this kind of information. Searched youtube without success.

Comment: Sorry but asking for some documentation is something that should not be asked at Stack Overflow. Please read Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: I didn't find any restrictions about asking for tutorial or documentation links. Not sure what is your problem. You can just ignore the question if you don't like it or at least post the link to the "Stack Overflow guidelines" so I can figure out how to ask it.

Comment: [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: So what would be the right question then ? Asking for each report one by one ?  For example how to get the relation between Customers and Orders ? You are not helping! I changed the question asking explicitly for documentation from Intuit. This should resolve your problem since there will be no "opinionated answers". Do you have info about Intuit documentation for QuickBooks Enterprise database ?

Comment: Maybe it means that you should ask the question in a less strict place? Reddit? I hope it helps.

Comment: Focus on a single report.  If you get the connection working once, you can repeat the same steps on the other reports.  Phrase the question around getting help making the connection between Crystal and the Quickbooks database.  Explain how you attempted the connection in a way that can be repeated by others.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Quickbooks, but I suspect you are going to need to configure an ODBC connection.  Try the steps [here](https://quickbooks.intuit.com/learn-support/en-us/help-article/data-systems/open-database-connectivity-odbc-driver-faqs/L1C6l99Fq_US_en_US).